# mySQL - How do I map/lookup one index to another and JOIN that other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, case

I have two tables with different indices that I can (manually) map from one to the other:

```
table1             table2
ID  Name  Data     ID  Name  Data
1   A     X        4   C1    11
2   B     Y        5   B2    22
3   C     Z        6   A3    33
```

A maps to A3, B maps to B2, C maps to C1

The result set I am hoping for is:

```
t1.ID  t1.Name  t1.Data  t2.ID  t2.Name  t2.Data
1      A        X        6      A3       33
2      B        Y        5      B2       22
3      C        Z        4      C1       11
```

This query fails because it doesn't recognize "map":

```
SELECT *,
   CASE t1.name
      WHEN 'A' THEN 'A3'
      WHEN 'B' THEN 'B2'
      WHEN 'C' THEN 'C1'
      END AS map
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t2.name = map)
```

This query fails because you can't use CASE inside an ON condition:
[This query actually works.  I had forgotten the END in my actual code.  Turns out that makes a big difference.]

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (t2.name = (SELECT CASE t1.name
      WHEN 'A' THEN 'A3'
      WHEN 'B' THEN 'B2'
      WHEN 'C' THEN 'C1'
      END ) )
```

So my questions are:

1) What Google search terms should I be using to find the solution I need?

2) What is the actual solution?

3) Can this be done *without* creating a lookup table (easiest solution)?

Comment: Your query works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=683e8ce56b80a07a7eab165ca87bfa0d Did you even try it?

Comment: It works now.  I added the END that I was missing once I realize what my actual problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause cannot access an alias defined in the `select` clause (because, basically, the former is evaluated *before* the latter).

You want the `case` expression in the `join` condition instead:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID t1_id, 
    t1.name t1_name, 
    t1.data t1_data, 
    t2.ID t2_id, 
    t2.name t2_name, 
    t2.data t2_data
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
    ON t2.name = CASE t1.name
      WHEN 'A' THEN 'A3'
      WHEN 'B' THEN 'B2'
      WHEN 'C' THEN 'C1'
    END
```

Note that it is better to use aliases in the `select` clause to disambiguate columns that have the same name across tables, as shown above;